# How to insert greek letter delta (∆) into header of flextable object?

Tags: r, unicode, ms-word, r-markdown, flextable

I am using RMarkdown to create a word document (I need the output to be in .docx format).

I'd like to use **flextable** (or any other package) to format my headers properly.

I'm trying to get the **greek symbol delta (∆)** to display properly... it seems possible because in the help pages here (https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/articles/format.html#display-function) the author successfully uses \u03BC to insert the "μ" symbol (and I can too if I use his code, below), but I can't get it to work for delta using **\u2206** or **\u0394**, if I replace \u03BC with either code below. The code I'm using produces this table, but I want to replace the highlighted bit with delta.

[image]

This is what I get when I try, for example, `\u2206`.

[image]

Any suggestions?

```
library(flextable)
if( require("xtable") ){
  mat <- round(matrix(c(0.9, 0.89, 200, 0.045, 2.0), c(1, 5)), 4)
  mat <- xtable(mat)
  ft <- xtable_to_flextable(x = mat, NA.string = "-")
  print(ft$col_keys)
  ft <- flextable::display(ft, i = 1, col_key = "X1", 
    pattern = "{{val}}{{pow}}", part = "header",
    formatters = list(val ~ as.character("R"), pow ~ as.character("2") ),
    fprops = list(pow = fp_text(vertical.align = "superscript", font.size = 8))
    )
  ft <- flextable::display(ft, i = 1, col_key = "X2", 
    pattern = "{{val}}{{pow}}", part = "header",
    formatters = list(val ~ as.character("\u03BC"), pow ~ as.character("x") ),
    fprops = list(pow = fp_text(vertical.align = "superscript", font.size = 8))
    )
  ft <- flextable::display(ft, i = 1, col_key = "rowname", 
    pattern = "{{val}}{{pow}}", part = "body",
    formatters = list(val ~ as.character("y"), pow ~ as.character("t-1") ),
    fprops = list(pow = fp_text(vertical.align = "subscript", font.size = 8))
    )
  ft <- set_header_labels(ft, X3 = "F-stat", X4 = "S.E.E", X5 = "DW", rowname = "")
  ft <- autofit(ft)
  ft
}
```

### Update

I am getting closer thanks to a helpful suggestion from David, but (not being very familiar with flextable) I am getting strange behaviour when I try to modify the header in the way suggested:

```
library(magrittr)
library(flextable)
library(officer)
AICtable <- data.frame(Model = "test", Parameters = 9, AICc = 4000, dAICc = 0, w = 1)
v.epi.aic <- flextable(AICtable) %>% 
font(fontname = "Times New Roman", part = "all") %>% 
flextable::display(col_key = "dAICc", part = "header",
                                pattern = "{{D}}{{A}}{{cbit}}", 
                                formatters = list(D ~ as.character("D"),
                                                  A ~ as.character("AIC"),
                                cbit ~ as.character("c") ),
                                fprops = list(D = fp_text(font.family = "Symbol"),
                                              A = fp_text(font.family = "Times New Roman"),
                                cbit = fp_text(vertical.align = "subscript")))

v.epi.aic
```

**Notice that column headers are now duplicated, and "AIC" appears before the "∆". The column names should be:**

Model, Parameters, AICc, ∆AICc, w (and the "c" in the ∆AICc should be a subscript).

[image]

Comment: Thanks Andrey, good idea. I've added some detail.

Comment: This might be the result of the font not containing a matching glyph. Can you try a few other fonts for the header and check if that helps?

Comment: @tarleb is right. The symbol probably does not exist in the used font table. You can change the font with `officer::fp_text(font.family = "...")`, default one is "arial".

Comment: Thanks David, getting closer... I will update my question, can you have a look?

Comment: I will (end of the week) :)

Comment: haha, thanks! Good enough for me ;) One hint: I don't get the "repeating header" behaviour when I comment out the line `font(fontname = "Times", part = "all")`.

Comment: I believe it's a bug in `display` - your code looks good :(

Comment: Ah, well, that's comforting on my end... :P I'll stay tuned!

Comment: Oh no! display is gone in a recent revision - anyone have this in the most recent version of flextable?

Answer (score 2):

Please use "\u394" instead of "\u0394" to generate the capital delta symbol